# How to use bitmap to send to another app

Tags: android, bitmap

can someone help me how to send an image to another application in android?

I want to send an image to be used as wallpaper, BBM display picture, and other applications that can use it (like WhatsApp, contacts, etc.)

I use this code, but it can only be used for sending text and not images as I want

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "This is my text to send.");
sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
startActivity(sendIntent);
```

Then I tried to use this code to set the wallpaper

```
public void setAsWallpaper(Bitmap bitmap) {
        try {           
            WallpaperManager wm = WallpaperManager.getInstance(_context);
            wm.setBitmap(bitmap);

            //disinimas
            Toast.makeText(_context,
                    _context.getString(R.string.toast_wallpaper_set),
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(_context,
                    _context.getString(R.string.toast_wallpaper_set_failed),
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```

the problem with the code, bitmap images directly applied as wallpaper. I wanted like sending text above, the user can choose to use another application. So I want a bitmap image that can later be used for wallpaper, BBM display picture, or other applications that support it

bitmap variable already contains the image that I want to, the images obtained from the internet with this code:

```
Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) fullImageView.getDrawable())
                .getBitmap();
```

I use this code and its work, but give me a message BBM: File not found, WhatsApp: File is not an image:

```
Bitmap icon = bitmap;
    Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_ATTACH_DATA);
    share.setType("image/jpeg");

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(Images.Media.TITLE, "title");
    values.put(Images.Media.MIME_TYPE, "image/jpeg");
    Uri uri = getContentResolver().insert(Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
            values);


    OutputStream outstream;
    try {
        outstream = getContentResolver().openOutputStream(uri);
        icon.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, outstream);
        outstream.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println(e.toString());
    }

    share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share Image"));
```

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for your help Antrromet, finally I solved my problem with the following code:

```
Bitmap icon = bitmap;
        //  Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        //  share.setType("image/*");

            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            values.put(Images.Media.TITLE, "title");
            values.put(Images.Media.MIME_TYPE, "image/*");
            Uri uri = getContentResolver().insert(Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                    values);


            OutputStream outstream;
            try {
                outstream = getContentResolver().openOutputStream(uri);
                icon.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, outstream);
                outstream.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.err.println(e.toString());
            }

            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_ATTACH_DATA);
            intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
            intent.setDataAndType(uri, "image/*");
            intent.putExtra("mimeType", "image/*");
            this.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Set as:"));
```

Now the image can be used as Wallpaper, BBM profile picture, WA display Picture, Coontact display picture, etc. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using the following code? It is use to [send binary data](http://developer.android.com/training/sharing/send.html#send-binary-content) to other apps.

```
Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uriToImage);
shareIntent.setType("image/jpeg");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, getResources().getText(R.string.send_to)));
```

Or if you dont have the URI with you but have the Bitmap instead, then try using the code as given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7662164/451951).

**UPDATE:**

Setting wallpaper and profile picture for BBM are totally different things and there is no common intent for them. For setting the wallpaper, you can try the following as given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22213878/android-set-wallpaper-using-the-set-wallpaper-intent).

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_ATTACH_DATA);
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
    intent.setDataAndType(uri, "image/jpeg");
    intent.putExtra("mimeType", "image/jpeg");
    this.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Set as:"));
```

For BBM, the APIs are not open for changing the user image. So you cannot do that through  your app.

Comment: I have Bitmap instead, I try this link http://stackoverflow.com/a/7662164/451951. I mean I want to send a bitmap that can be made as wallpaper, BBM display picture, WhatsApp display picture, etc. Using the code in the link allowed me to share pictures and not set it as wallpaper or BBM display picture as I wanted.

Comment: I get this message: BBM : File not found, WhatsApp: File is not an image, see my question, I was update it