# Set as Wallpaper intent dialog?

Tags: android, android-intent, wallpaper

I am trying to create my own wallpaper app and I can't figure out how to start this intent?

[image]

What is this intent? How do I pass image to device default wallpaper app?

Comment: duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22213878/android-set-wallpaper-using-the-set-wallpaper-intent

Comment: The answer in the question you mentioned does not work for me. It gives me "All apps associated with this action have been turned off, blocked, or are not installed" dialog

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following code snippet:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_ATTACH_DATA);
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);//add this if your targetVersion is more than Android 7.0+
intent.setDataAndType(uri, "image/jpeg");
intent.putExtra("mimeType", "image/jpeg");
this.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Set as:"));
```

PS:uri should get from FileProvider in Android 7.0+ if your targetVersion is more than7.0+

Comment: This gave me the following error: "All apps associated with this action have been turned off, blocked, or are not installed."

Comment: Which Anroid version about your device?

Comment: I did something in my Huawei Honor V8,and it works fine.By the way you should add `Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION` in your Intent at Android 7.0+.I'll reedit my answer.

Comment: Will check and update you tomorrow. But it was tested on api 21 and 26

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
private void startWallpaper(){
    final Intent pickWallpaper = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SET_WALLPAPER);
    Intent chooser = Intent.createChooser(pickWallpaper,"set wallpaeper");
    startActivity(chooser);
}
```

ref is [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent#ACTION_SET_WALLPAPER)

In your manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_WALLPAPER"></uses-permission>
```

If you want to pass own img, could do like below:

```
WallpaperManager wpm = WallpaperManager.getInstance(context);
InputStream ins = new URL("absolute/path/of/image").openStream();
wpm.setStream(ins);
```

Comment: How to pass image with first method?

Second method didn't work