# How to get default "Set wallpaper" intent

Tags: android, wallpaper, android-wallpaper

I m trying to set image as wallpaper from stored in drawable folder with default android way like this 
[image]

I have tried as answered in other questions
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22213878/android-set-wallpaper-using-the-set-wallpaper-intent?noredirect=1).

But i m getting error as 
 "No apps can perform this action"

My code to get uri-

```
Uri uri=Uri.parse("android.resource://drawable/sharingan.jpg");

Intent intent=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_ATTACH_DATA);
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
intent.setDataAndType(uri,"image/*");
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
intent.putExtra("mimeType","image/*");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent,"Set as"));
```

Is there another way to achieve this?
Or is there something wrong with my uri ?

Comment: can you see if uri is null or not?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android - Set Wallpaper using the "Set Wallpaper" intent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22213878/android-set-wallpaper-using-the-set-wallpaper-intent)

Comment: Could you try setting the MIME type to be of `image/jpeg` instead of `image/*`, as other answers have suggested in the duplicate? You're also adding a redundant extra to the intent (`intent.putExtra("mimeType", "image/*")`).

Answer (score 0):

Construct the uri object like following

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse(ContentResolver.SCHEME_ANDROID_RESOURCE +
 "://" + getResources().getResourcePackageName(R.drawable.sharingan)
 + '/' + getResources().getResourceTypeName(R.drawable.sharingan) + '/' + getResources().getResourceEntryName(R.drawable.sharingan) );
```