# How to set Wallpaper without WallpaperManager

Tags: android, android-intent, android-wallpaper, android-glide

I am using Glide to cache Images in an ImageView.
Now I want to set the image in the ImageView as the wallpaper of the phone without using the WallpaperManager, because the WallpaperManager does not give the option to crop/pan the Image like the wallpaper setting of default gallery app does.

I want to set Wallpaper using:

> Intent.ACTION_ATTACH_DATA

or

> Intent.ACTION_SET_WALLPAPER

but I don't know how to pass the Bitmap/drawable from the ImageView to that intent.
Here's my code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_ATTACH_DATA);
            intent.setDataAndType(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, "image/*");
            intent.putExtra("mimeType", "image/jpeg");
            intent.putExtra("image", imageView.getDrawingCache());
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Wallpaper"));
```

When I execute this code, I get a pull-up menu with installed galleries to select wallpaper.
And when I choose one of them i get a Toast-

> "Cannot load the image."

which is probably because I'm not passing any image to the Intent.
Please Help, I've been searching for this for hours.

I found Similar questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22213878/android-set-wallpaper-using-the-set-wallpaper-intent), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18700161/android-set-wallpaper-using-intent) & [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18778555/android-set-as-wallpaper-functionality'), but none of them worked for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, as I've solved the problem, now I'm writing the solution here(in case anybody else needs it).

```
    myDir = new File(root + "/Wallpy/");     //this is the name of the containing folder
    final File imageFile = new File(myDir, "abcd.jpg");     //name of the image file
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_ATTACH_DATA);
                    intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(imageFile), "image/*");
                    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Wallpaper"));
```

where, `imageFile` is the File that is needed to be set as wallpaper.